# ssh passwordless login to root account

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, login, root, key-authentication

When installing Kali-Linux distro version 6.0
the assisted installation process ask for a user name (I entered Joe, could be any other...) and it created the user Joe (with the same privileges as the root user )

I configured the **ssh** server to login with **Private Key**

When I connect from a client the console always open in *standard user mode*

then I have to do a 'sudo su' and enter password to enter in *root mode*

I edited the server '**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**' and changed:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
RSAAuthentication yes
StrictModes yes
```

> Restared the service... reboot... etc.

but the ssh client console always open in standard user mode (connects OK with the private-key and no password)

should by now be opening the console in root user mode!

?any ideas...

*PS: I'm using Kali 6.0*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "created only 1 user Joe (that is root)"? Did you assign ID 0 to Joe? Please show the `/etc/passwd` entry of user Joe. Where did you generate what keys? How exactly did you set up the authorized keys? How exactly do you connect? Working as `root` permanently is dangerous. You should work as a normal user and only use `sudo` when it is absolutely necessary. Most permission problems can be solved in different ways. BTW: [Kali is not for beginners](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/330217)

Comment: about the comments... not my opinion... ;-) the question seams clear enough (if it is not please state the part you don't understand)... also if the question are very long and complex it becomes TL;DR,,, ;-)) also the comments are a valuable source on information to understand what other users insights about the question... for many times I acquired better information from the comments than from the answers ;-)))

Comment: My comment contains several questions you could answer if you want to solve your problem. Your statements in the question and your comment contradict my knowledge about Linux, so I suspect a misunderstanding on your side. That's why I asked nearly everything that may help to clarify this. The main point is: When you connect via `ssh` you will have the privileges of the specified user. If this user has ID 0 you will have `root` privileges otherwise not. **No**, the user Joe created during install does **not** have the same privileges as `root`, but this user is permitted to use `sudo`.

Comment: "Kali Linux 6.0" does not make much sense.  Do you mean "Kali Linux 2022.4"?

Comment: Yes @kusalananda... but just use "uname -a" and you'll know what I'm referring to...

Comment: Yes @Bodo... I know that... but can you elaborate on "user created during install does not have the same privileges as root".... just for add to the discussion and try to enlight us... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have configured the key authentication for user `Joe` and specifying that you're logging in as that user, that's what you are getting.

If you want to log in directly "in root mode", then you would have to set up a second copy of your SSH public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file **of the `root` user**, and also tell your SSH client that you want to log in as user `root`.

By the way, `sudo su` is at least 20 years obsolete way to access a root session, as it first uses `sudo` to become root, and then `su` to adjust the environment. About since year 2000, you have been able to do both things as a single step with `sudo -i`.

Comment: Hi @telcom... For security reasons I only enabled the "Joe" account for remote login... and like I said the SSH login occurs OK (so the problem is not the key-authentication)... the annoyance is that it does not open the console already in root mode... and having to enter " sudo -i " and the password is time consuming... and keylogger friendly ;-)))

Comment: In Unix/Linux, there is no such thing as "user Joe in root mode". When you use `sudo -i`, `sudo su` or whatever, you stop being "user Joe" and start being "user root". If you want to "log in directly in root mode", then you must log in as user `root`. If your local system has a keylogger installed by an attacker, the attacker could also have copied your SSH keys.

Comment: thanks for your answer @telcom... what you said is true... and can easily be confirmed after a "sudo -s" and a "whoami" command... but as you for sure know,,, when an attacker goes to a login prompt in a linux box... the only certainty he has about user names... is that are a "root" user... and then just press-on with passwords (hence the root  disable for SSH interactive login)... about the copy of files/keys... I do not want to enter a discussion of how much easy is to get the keys that you type in your console... than those files... ;-)

Comment: You can configure the server's SSHD to accept only key-based authentication and reject all passwords, even the correct ones... and for servers accessible from the internet, I would very much recommend doing so whenever possible. And for root logins, you can put `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow direct root access by SSH using key-based authentication only, even if you've configured it to accept password auth for other users.

Comment: @ZEE The ordinary Kali Linux installation gives you a system with a root user that has no password set (not "an empty password", but no password, which means there is no way to log in as root directly). This is by design, as the root account should only be accessed via `sudo` for specific administrative tasks.